# How to find a particular value in XML which has namespaces in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML string as follows:

```
xmlstr = u'''<w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" 
xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" 
xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" 
xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" 
xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" 
xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" 
xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" 
xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" 
xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" 
xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" 
xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" 
xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" 
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" 
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:b/>
    <w:noProof/>
    <w:sz w:val="20"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:drawing>
    <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
      <wp:extent cx="6324600" cy="2607945"/>
      <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
      <wp:docPr id="6819" name="Picture 6819"/>
      <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
      </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
      <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
        <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
          <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:nvPicPr>
              <pic:cNvPr id="6819" name="Screenshot 2019-06-27 at 11.59.23 AM.png"/>
              <pic:cNvPicPr/>
            </pic:nvPicPr>
            <pic:blipFill>
              **<a:blip r:embed="rId14" cstate="print">**
                <a:extLst>
                  <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                    <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                  </a:ext>
                </a:extLst>
              </a:blip>
              <a:stretch>
                <a:fillRect/>
              </a:stretch>
            </pic:blipFill>
            <pic:spPr>
              <a:xfrm>
                <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                <a:ext cx="6324600" cy="2607945"/>
              </a:xfrm>
              <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                <a:avLst/>
              </a:prstGeom>
            </pic:spPr>
          </pic:pic>
        </a:graphicData>
      </a:graphic>
    </wp:inline>
  </w:drawing>
</w:r>
'''
```

The lines of interest to me in the above XML string are:

```
    <pic:nvPicPr>
      <pic:cNvPr id="6819" name="Screenshot 2019-06-27 at 11.59.23 AM.png"/>
      <pic:cNvPicPr/>
    </pic:nvPicPr>
    <pic:blipFill>
      <a:blip r:embed="rId14" cstate="print">
```

I want to extract the values `"Screenshot 2019-06-27 at 11.59.23 AM.png"` and `"rId14"` from the XML string.

I tried using the root.findall() method. But for some reason, I'm unable to retrieve those values. Can someone help me to retrieve these values using Python's XML library? Below is the code that I tried, and it's obviously not working.

```
from io import StringIO
from xml.etree import ElementTree

my_namespaces = dict([node for _, node in ElementTree.iterparse(StringIO(xmlstr), events=['start-ns'])])
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr) 
print(root.findall('pic.pic', my_namespaces))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the wanted data:

```
for pic in root.findall('.//pic:pic', my_namespaces):
    cNvPr_elem = pic.find("pic:nvPicPr/pic:cNvPr", my_namespaces)
    name_attr = cNvPr_elem.get("name")
    blip_elem = pic.find("pic:blipFill/a:blip", my_namespaces)
    embed_attr = blip_elem.get("{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships}embed")

    print(name_attr)
    print(embed_attr)
```

Output:

```
Screenshot 2019-06-27 at 11.59.23 AM.png
rId14
```

Notes:

- `pic.pic` in the question was changed to `.//pic:pic`.
- To get the value of the `r:embed` attribute, the namespace URI must be used. The `get()` method does not take a prefix-namespace mapping like `findall()`.